# Is determinism a condition for physics?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-physics

Here, Physics is expressed in mathematical equations. The relation between the various physical entities referenced by the equation is determined exactly.

This is just as true of Hiesenbergs Uncertainty principle in Quantum Mechanics as it is in Classical Physics.

In this view, determinism is built into Physics itself.

But, in other physical, or properly cosmological doctrines as espoused by the Milesian materialists or the Carvaka school, is this still true?

Comment: Determinism is a condition of the observer(s).

Comment: Is there an example of an equation where the relation between its objects is not determined exactly? The language of physics is mathematics, but does the precision of its language translate into epistemological precision? Newtown's laws were just as exactly determined as Einsteins, but one was much less accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Determinism is **not** required for Physics, even for "expressed in mathematical equations", which incidently was not always the case. True, mathematical models tend to be deterministic, but that's only because physicists tend to "express in mathematical equations" the things that are deterministic. That's the nature of **most** equations.

Things that are not deterministic tend to be averaged out, and the average quantity gets all the attention, precisely because it tends to be deterministic. In the cases when averaging out does not lead to determinism either the physicists basically give up "expressing in mathematical equations" and concentrate on empirical studies.

Here are some diverse examples of nondeterminism in modern physics, each example intentionally of different nature of nondeterminsim:

Things that can be averaged out: statistical processes, quantum states versus expectations of observables, etc.

Things that cannot be meaningfully averaged, studied empirically: plasma dynamics, electron beams.

Things for which **rejection** of determinism is of principal importance: "backward" predictions in thermodynamics, arrow of time.